# Angular - Can't sort the data when changing quaryParams

Tags: javascript, typescript

In `component.ts`

```
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private store$: Store<UsersState>,
    private router: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onFilterByIncome();
    this.router.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      const param = params['tab'];
      console.log(param);

      if (param === 0) {
        this.onFilterByIncome(); //dispatch metods
      }
      if (param === 1) {
        this.onFilterByOutcome();
      }
      if (param === 2) {
        this.onFilterByLoan();
      }
      if (param === 3) {
        this.onFilterByInvestment();
      }
    });
  }

//Like this
  onFilterByIncome() {
    this.store$.dispatch(new UsersFilterByIncomeAction());
  }
```

I need the data coming into the component to change when the params is changed.

I tried different ways, but it didn't work out for me. With such a code as now, it does not work for me.

Comment: where exactly are you getting the error? is your `console.log(param)` not subscribing to the change in params ?

Comment: I don't get an error, I just don't have functions called and console.log() in if. How i can subscribe on param?

Comment: I just need the function to be called when changing the queryParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are doing a strict equality comparison (using triple equals `===`) between a **string** query param value and a **number**. An activated route query param value will always be a string because a URL is only ever a string.

```
const param: string = params['tab'];  <-- returns a string type, i.e. '0'.

if (param === 0) {. <-- strict equality check will not pass even if the param is '0'.
  this.onFilterByIncome();
}
```

You can fix this by updating your comparison value to also be a string type. (I'd recommend this fix)

```
if (param === '0') {
  this.onFilterByIncome();
}
```

or you can do a loose equality comparison by using a double equals. `==`

```
if (param == 0) {
  this.onFilterByIncome();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, but I didn't understand why it didn't work with numbers, params['tab'] return string?

Comment: @Vladon305, Yes params['tab'] will return a string. i.e. '1' or '34'.